# Undefined strikethrough on the website

Tags: html, css

[This](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/clf/) website shows some text which is strike through. Its nowhere mentioned in the CSS or html as far as I could look. Here is the code for it,

```
<div style="width:100%;height:259px;background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/child.png');    color: #f3ffcd;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row health_text">
        394,000 Children die in Pakistan before their fifth birthdays due to poor access to healthcare facilities.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
font-size: 36px;
    margin: 85px 0;
    font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
```

Comment: For those who are downvoting the answer, please provide a response to why you are downvoting it.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, but assuming you want to know why the text has strikethrough, it's because the whole thing is wrapped in `<s>` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it is the `s` tag which is doing that :

It has property : `text-decoration: line-through;`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `<del></del>` tags, this should be what you're looking for.

Comment: No idea why someone would downvote you; your answer seems plausible..!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :)))))))))

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which (presumably) is how that specific web site does it.

Comment: If the question was written correctly then there would be no misunderstanding. Or if a question was actually asked...